# final response = await get(url); not working

Tags: flutter, dart, url, async-await, get

```dart
  final url = Uri.parse('https://aged-cherry-5206.fly.dev/sum?one=43&two=-1');
  final response = await get(url);
```

cause: SocketExcpetion(SocketException: Connection failed ( OS Error:Operation not permitetted, errno = 1), address = aged-cherry-5206.fly.def, port = 443)

Comment: A plain Dart program prints Sum: 42 - so there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the back end. Have you tried a plain Dart example - or in DartPad?

Comment: did you check your internet connection, it is stable also if you use the internet in a mobile app through data internet make sure the data is not empty. this type of exception often occurs due to the internet is not available.